# I have a 2013 Nissan Sentra and I hit a lot hole

Tags: tires, nissan, wheels

I hit a pot hole the other week in the back rear tire and bent the rim, someone hammered it out for me a little but I still get a noisy wobble when I drive it is not so severe when I’m driving faster but at slow speeds and stops and go it is noticeable. What should I do as far from replacing the rim is there anything else I should check or have done?

Comment: Note that it could also be that your tire is damaged.  Severe impact can break the cords and then the tire is no longer round.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the rim/wheel. I hit a curb. I ground and polished away the visible damage and replaced the tire. It could not be balanced although the tire shop saw nothing wrong. Measurement found a small distortion of the rim. The work necessary to correct it would have cost more than a replacement rim. PS: Salvage yard rims are much lower cost than a dealer.

Answer (score 0):

No responsible person would hammer out an aluminum rim.  With steel it is possible if the damage is minor.  Even so, the wheel would need to be re-balanced. If it was not at a proper tire shop with the kit for safely dismounting tires and the balance machine, then you can count on the repair being done badly.

There are aftermarket companies which specialize in supplying factory-same rims and hub caps.  So they should be able to supply a matching rim.